# calling saveAsync changes ChangeKey

Tags: outlook-web-addins

Calling Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync on a draft message without changing the message itself changes the value of the ChangeKey.

Since Outlook JS does not provide event notifying of property changes ( on an item ), I was going to compare ChangeKeys of the draft message over time.  To do so, one needs to get a rest Id first.  Office.context.mailbox.item.Id is undefined for draft, forcing a call to SaveAsync, which then changes the ChangeKey, which defeats the purpose of the exercise ( as we'll incorrectly assume that the message has changed ).

Outlook team, is this something you are going to fix?  What's the workaround to find out if a draft item has changed?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you plan to use the information that the draft has changed? Are there particular properties or fields (body, attachment subject) that you are interested in?  Also, have you checked if Outlook push notification works for your scenario? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/notify-rest-operations

Comment: We have a taskpane that reflects state of the message - recipients( to/cc/bcc), subject.  In the draft, those properties change and the taskpane needs to be updated as they do.  In the COM add-in, we listen for Item.PropertyChange event.  There is a number of requests for this event on UserVoice.  To work around this limitation, we used the ChangeKey and ran into the problem described in the OP.  Push notifications is not a viable solution for our application.

Comment: This is a list of all properties we listen to ( regular messages, meeting requests, appointments):
"Subject","Location","TO","CC","BCC","StartUTC",
"StartInStartTimeZone","EndUTC,"EndInEndTimeZone

Comment: Some of what you require is implemented in the Preview API set. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/office/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/outlook-requirement-set-preview?view=office-js

Namely Recipients, AppointmentTime, and Recurrence Changed Events. For the rest please provide feedback at our UserVoice: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins

Comment: Thanks MSFT team, addHandlerAsync is the right first step.  Here's the link to the userVoice item that asks for additional properties that should be supported:

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/10315167-provide-an-event-to-let-outlook-add-in-respond-to

Comment: Also, calling saveAsync without changing the message (just to get an ID) should NOT modify the ChangeKey.  This negatively affects Exchange sync solutions and workarounds for the current limitations of addHandlerAsync.  Here's the userVoice link:
https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/35231644-bug-saveasync-modifies-changekey-when-there-are-no